# wordpress blog posts aren't clickable on mobile

Tags: wordpress, mobile, wordpress-theming, blogs

Links on my blog are no longer clickable on mobile, the posts show up on the main page and I can scroll, but when I try to click nothing happens. The desktop page is not affected.

When I turn all of my plugins off, the issue goes away, but the design of the blog is wrong. I then went through and deactivated each plugin individually a few times to find the culprit, but the issue persists when various plugins are turned on and off - I can't pinpoint it. If anyone can assist that would be great. Thank you.

Comment: Are you able to link to the site?

Turning off one plugin or turning them on one at a time and checking would point to wish one is the issue. 

Without a link to the site its near impossible to help you.

Comment: Can you share link?